# Migrating to XOAUTH2 and accessing other users unread message count in google apps for education

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, gmail, google-apps

We've got a google apps for eduction domain, and until recently we were happily using gmail_xoath and imap to get other users unread email counts to display on their portal front page.

We've been using Nicolas' excellent gmail_xoauth gem found here.

github.com/nfo/gmail_xoauth

And our code looked like this.

```
require 'gmail_xoauth'
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, usessl = true, certs = nil, verify = false)
imap.authenticate('XOAUTH', @email,
        :two_legged => true,
        :consumer_key => consumer_key,
        :consumer_secret => consumer_secret()
)
@messages_count = imap.status('INBOX', ['UNSEEN'])['UNSEEN']
imap.disconnect
```

Notice how we're using the consumer_key and the consumer_secret that we got from our google apps admin in the Manage OAuth key and secret for this domain section.

Now we need to upgrade to Oauth2.  gmail_xoauth does support XOAUTH2, and I followed this procedure to test that.

Create a project in my google developer console, using the installed app option. I'm signed into google as a domain admin for our google apps domain.

Using this page, https://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/wiki/OAuth2DotPyRunThrough, send off the client_id and client_secret to obtain an Access Token. During that process I give the application authority to access my email by a consent screen.

Stick that access_token into this code

```
require 'gmail_xoauth'
@access_token = "access_token"
@email = "my email address"
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, usessl = true, certs = nil, verify = false)
imap.authenticate('XOAUTH2', @email, @access_token)
@messages_count = imap.status('INBOX', ['UNSEEN'])['UNSEEN']
imap.disconnect
```

That works, happy days!!

The problem I now have, is how do I tell my google apps domain to allow that project to access other users email data, wihtout asking them if they wany to allow it?

I tried this approach

Sign into Google Domain Admin Console as an admin

Click on Security

CLick Show More

Click Advanced

Click Manage API CLient Access

Enter the Client ID of the project created

Enter the Scope for IMAP access, https://mail.google.com/

Once that was done, I still hept getting Invalid Credentials errors when trying to count the number of messages in other users mailboxes, as denoted by their email address.

I'm pretty sure I've misread some docs somewhere, and I'm doing something stupid, but I can't seem to work out what it is.

I'm thinking that maybe adding the project like that to the google apps domain isn't the correct way of authorising an application to access other users data in the domain.  I've seen service accounts mentioned, and migrating to Oauth2, and various other possible solutions, but can't get any of them to work.

What I'd really like to know is what is the suggested approach that definitely works, and then I'll concentrate on that.

If anyone has any advice tips links, anything at all, I'd be eternally grateful.

Matt

UPDATE 1

I've been in touch with Nicolas who is the creator of the gmail_xoauth gem and he has confirmed that in it's current state, the gem doesn't allow the use of service accounts, and therefore cannot access other users gmail data in our google apps for education domain.

I've passed some example java code onto Nicolas that accomplishes accessing other users gmail data in our google apps for education domain, and he's going to have a look into adapting the gem to allow such a mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

In order to authorize an app for a whole domain ("two-legged OAuth"), you need to create a Service Account. There is documentation at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#serviceaccount and https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount. You may be able to use the Ruby libraries at https://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/wiki/OAuth2.

Comment: Thanks Jamie for your response.  I did look at using service accounts, but all the libraries I've been using don't seem to have any options for using a service account, they all want the old style client_id and client_secret, which has been deprecated.  I realise now I do need a service account though, and have made some progress here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051616/accessing-google-domain-users-email-data-with-xoauth2  That link you sent me wont work, for the very same reason, that library needs a client_id and a client_secret, that's old style.

Comment: Your suggestion is correct though, service accounts are the way to go, but I can't upvote your answer yet, not enough rep points :-(.  I'll try to remember to upvote it once I reach the dizzy heights of 15.  Thanks again.

Answer (score -3):

To successfully Migrate to XOAUTH2 and accessing other users unread message count in google apps for education, It is fairly simple, all you really have to do is take the file that you wish to migrate, you select and move it into the same file as your program. then try to run it again and it should work.

I really do hope that this helped you, with your troubles.
If it did not I am indeed sorry.

If this worked please let me know :)

Comment: Hi Jason.  What file are you talking about?  Do you have any links to the documentation you followed to get this to work?

Comment: Oh I apologize, did my comment not help you ?

Comment: Not really Jason, as I don't know what you mean, hence the questions back.